# Get vertex-coordinates of an image with the help of canvas imageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection, intersection, getimagedata

I need to get the position of each edge for some sprites and have no idea how to accomplish this. Here's an example image of what I mean:

[image]

I tried something with `canvas` and `getImageData` but not success.

I need it for some collision detection, the result has to be an array like this one:

```
[
    [-150, -120],
    [150, -120],
    [150, 60],
    [90, 120],
    [-90, 120],
    [-150, 60]
]
```

Is there already a simple algorithm/solution out there in the wild?

**Update**

Here's an example of what I mean. Use your arrow keys to rotate/scale the sprite
http://html5quintus.com/quintus/examples/sprite/

Comment: So you need to know the vertexes of the polygon? Are we talking about a polygon, by the way?

Comment: @MaxArt Yeah, you're completely right! :) Any ideas?

Comment: Not easy. Basically, you have to scan the canvas with `getImageData`, detecting the border and following it checking for change of directions. I'm not writing an answer for that, sorry.

Comment: @MaxArt No problem, good to know that your thoughts are the same like mine :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to get the x, y coordinates is to open up the image in an image editor. I would recommend GIMP which is free. If you are look for some kind of program that will do this for you... I'm not aware of one.